# How to add show button to active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want add button for showing query in active admin. Request to get query count pretty heavy for DB, and I want to show it only on demand (button press), for now it make request always when page render. Are there any funds from the box to do this? [image: active admin]

Comment: Try to find answer here https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html

Comment: Probably best to use AJAX for this.